# How do I get Beyond Compare to Ignore non text characters

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

My problem is twofold. I'm using Beyond Compare integrated with Visual Studio 2015 as my Compare/Merge tool. While looking at my list of 'Pending Changes', I see a file which if I 'Right Click -> Source Control -> Compare with Latest Version', I can see no differences in the text compare as you can see below:

[image: Text Compare - Note (for later) the bit I've highlighted]

However, if I do a hex compare of the same, I get the following result:

[image: Hex Compare - BOM at the start]

I can see it's somehow gotten the EF BB BF at the starting and the Beyond Compare notes this difference with a red bar in the left side window.

On other occasions, I've seen files in 'Pending Changes' with 0d0a at the end which is apparently for a newline character but again Beyond Compare doesn't show this as a difference in Text Compare (I've seen Git GUi show it as a difference in the past).

How can I get Beyond Compare to ignore changes like these that don't show up in the Text Compare when it considers a particular file as a 'pending change' so I don't see it in the 'Pending Changes' window in the first place?

OR, if that's not at all possible,

How can I get Beyond Compare to show these changes in the default text compare so I can undo them easily?

Comment: The EF-BB-BF at the start of the file means UTF-8 with BOM. On the right hand side of the top image, above the file contents, you can see the "BOM" underlined in red.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. Missed the underlined BOM text; I could use this along with Chris Kennedy's answer below to (somewhat) resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the extra newline character show as a difference in the Text Compare:

1. Click the **Rules** toolbar button (referee icon).
2. In the **Importance** tab, check **Compare line endings (PC/Mac/Unix)**.
3. To make it the default for new Text Compare sessions, change the dropdown from **Use for this view only** to **Also update session defaults** before you click OK.

If you turn on **View > Visible Whitespace**, the extra newline character will show as a red difference. When this setting is on, it will also show Windows style newline on one side and Unix style newline on the other side as a difference.

As AdrianHHH said, the EF BB BF is a UTF-8 byte order mark. It isn't possible to add or remove a BOM in the Text Compare. In the Hex Compare, it is possible to delete the BOM from a file.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This looks like what I need.